# What is the tool to make a demo mobile user interface?

Tags: tools, mobile-application

How do make a demo picture of a phone app, mainly for use on this site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are editing your post, there are various edit tools above the text area. One has a pencil drawing on a wireframe.

[image]

Click that.